# How to create a jar file?

Tags: unit-testing, selenium, groovy, junit, geb

How to create an executable jar project for Geb-Groovy based project in eclipse.
The following is the directory structure:
[image: Directory Structure of Geb Project]

the pages package contains the groovy files
the testclasses package contains the test cases groovy files
the utils package contains the groovy files to read data of excel sheets.

Detailed instructions for creating the jar file would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If the project you are working with is a gradle project I would recommend looking at a task called "shadowJar" https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow

in build.gradle would have something like this:

```
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"

mainClassName = '<Name of your Main Class>' //This will act as the jar's main point of entry the 'Main' method found in this class will be executed when the jar is executed

shadowJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}
```

Then you simply make a run the shadowJar task and a jar file is generated in your build folder. It should also contain all your dependencies as well.